# Finding Serial Number when Associated Azure AD device only shows name

Tags: azure-active-directory, autopilot

Occasionally I find a device in Azure (under a user > devices) that doesn't have S/N naming convention. It has a generic DESKTOP-name. If I knew the serial, I could search that in AutoPilot list, and then find the associated device. But I don't know how to do it the other way around.

Obviously there is some link between these two records. Is there a way to get the S/N with a powershell search or some other spot? Currently the only way to do this is to click through all the AutoPilot S/N's, pull up properties until I find the associated name. With thousands of devices, this is not feasible. See images below.

If I have the S/N, I can search it in AutoPilot, look at properties and find the Associated Azure AD device. But not the other way around.

I want to know how to take Azure Ad device Name: DESKTOP-IMMKAOT to find the S/N.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for posting your query.  From your description I could understand that you are looking to find device serial number with device name. Currently we don't have a direct way to get device serial number from Azure AD devices. Here are the following workaround you could follow from UI.

- When device hash is uploaded then the object created in Azure AD with
  name==serial number of the device. (The device is not provisioned yet).
- Once device is provisioned the serial number and name of the device
  could be sorted from MEM console by navigating to Devices -> Windows
  -> Windows Devices -> and sort the device with serial number or device name and > hardware.
- Another way around is to have serial number in the device name (post
  device provisioning). This is possible by adding device name in
  deployment profile. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/autopilot/profiles

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I realise this question is a few months old but I came across this while looking for something else Azure Ad related and as I had the exact same problem this morning I thought I would share my solution.

- Copy the Device ID from Azure Portal.
- Open Microsoft Graph Explorer -
  https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer.
- Authenticate to your tenant if not automatically logged in.
- In the query window select Get and enter the following query:
  https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/deviceManagement/windowsAutopilotDeviceIdentities?$filter=azureActiveDirectoryDeviceId
  eq 'Azure Device ID'.

Where 'Azure Device ID' is the one you copied from the Azure Portal.

This will return the Autopilot id, group tag, serial number and a bunch of other information to locate the device in Autopilot.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I'll try it out and let you know.

Comment: PmcT77 -- this 100% worked. I had to have an admin provide rights to run the query, but once we did, it worked. I have one more question if you happen to run across this.

There is one other situation -- that is when I go to a user > Devices -- and they have a NON-AUTOPILOT (and non-intune) device with a Blue Icon (instead of the pink/purple AutoPilot icon). The query does not work for those IDs. Do you know if Graph has capability to dig out those S/Ns?